# use service for ng-class in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

Do you think if it's possible to use a service/directive/... for `ng-class` ?

What I mean is that I use the same `ng-class` in several partial view.

```
<div ng-repeat="s in statut">
   <div ng-class="{'draft': s.statut_id == 5, 'to-do': s.statut_id == 10, 'no-go': s.statut_id == 500, 'go': s.statut_id == 1000}"></div>
</div>
```

The problem comes when I want to add a new class, I have to change it on every view, but I could forget to change any of these views.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: I think a quick hack could be $rootScope = Myservice in a run block or a dedicate controller for the ng-repeat  $scope = Myservice

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic example of what you're wanting to achieve. This would best be done as a directive. After-all, `ngClass` is a directive itself.

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XBwkI2HCc4js725NEqg0?p=preview)**

All that happens here is to make use of the `template` property that can be applied to a directive. Here you define your HTML.

Directive:

```
app.directive('myngclass', function() {
    return  {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        template: "<div class='data' ng-class = \"{'five': d.id == 5, 'six': d.id == 6, 'seven': d.id == 7, 'eight': d.id == 8, 'nine': d.id == 9}\">{{d.name}}</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        }};
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">
    <myngclass></myngclass>
</div>
```

I don't exactly what needs to be contained within each div, so the example is very basic. But it should be a good starting point to get you where you need to go.

Comment: Yeah, your example works. But this needs to be in a `ng-repeat` with a particular name, here is `d`, right ? Is it possible that the directive can be based on the `ng-repeat` above ?

Comment: @Steffi I'm not really sure what you mean. The directive is being repeated over. If you don't want to do it as an element, you could put it as an attribute with the `ng-repeat`. It'd behave exactly the same. Let me know if I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what you mean. Correct. You can change the `d` to be whatever you are repeating over.